# Flutter error: Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am using `authStateChanges().listen` to see when user is logged in or logged out and where the app should take them. But for some reason I get the following error.

```
E/flutter (29194): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
E/flutter (29194): Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.
```

I need `if (user == null)` to be `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil` due to the fact that I need to trigger `dispose()` from another page

```
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
      UserModel loggedInUser = UserModel();
      User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      //  if (mounted) {
      if (user == null) {
        print(
            '------------------------------------------------------User is currently signed out!');
        print(user);
        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => const LoginScreen()),
            (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      } else {
        print(user);
        print(
            '--------------------------------------------------User is signed in!');
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
    const loadData()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      }
//}
    });
```

Comment: Is this the only place you are using the user? Does the stack trace of thrown error correspond to the file and the line where this code snippet is found? 

This error is thrown because as user becomes null from FirebaseAuth, some widgets that were showing, if user was non-null, become immediately removed, however, you are still in one way or the other relying on state or properties that should be available when the user was non-null, even now the user is null. So check again.

Comment: Assuming the code above is part of a Widget. When this widget is not shown, the listener still exists ... but is unable to find the `context`.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you are using a context belonging to a `State` that is no longer alive (Guess it is just a normal Stateful Page and lives a short time).

What you are trying to do is routing but without context. You can use [GlobalKey](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux/issues/5#issuecomment-361215074) to achieve this,

Then you can register the callback listener somewhere like your `main.dart`.